# Sum a Column based on Value, then Sort in Descending order based on Gender

Tags: r

I am trying to find the top five most common names, split by male/female, over the span of some amount of years. This is from the "babynames" package in R.

I have this code that works:

```
babynames %>%
  group_by(sex, name) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(n)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total)) %$%
  split(., sex)
```

Which produces this output:

```
# A tibble: 67,046 x 3
# Groups:   sex [1]
   sex   name        total
   <chr> <chr>       <int>
 1 F     Mary      4123200
 2 F     Elizabeth 1629679
 3 F     Patricia  1571692
 4 F     Jennifer  1466281
 5 F     Linda     1452249
 6 F     Barbara   1434060
 7 F     Margaret  1246649
 8 F     Susan     1121440
 9 F     Dorothy   1107096
10 F     Sarah     1073895
# … with 67,036 more rows

$M
# A tibble: 40,927 x 3
# Groups:   sex [1]
   sex   name      total
   <chr> <chr>     <int>
 1 M     James   5150472
 2 M     John    5115466
 3 M     Robert  4814815
 4 M     Michael 4350824
 5 M     William 4102604
 6 M     David   3611329
 7 M     Joseph  2603445
 8 M     Richard 2563082
 9 M     Charles 2386048
10 M     Thomas  2304948
# … with 40,917 more rows
```

But I need to find another approach as well.

This is what I have come up with, but I can't get it to equal the numbers in the code above:

```
summary <- babynames %>% group_by(sex, name) %>% split(., sex)
summaryFemales <- summary$F
summaryFemales
summaryFemales1 <- summarize(summaryFemales, net=sum(n))
summaryFemales1
head(summaryFemales1, 10)
```

In here, the first line successfully groups and splits the data based on if the person is male or female. Then I try and make a subset of summary, called summaryFemales to only show the female data. Then I try and add all of the times the name has appeared in each year by using summarize() but that results in this:

```
# A tibble: 67,046 x 3
# Groups:   sex [1]
   sex   name        net
   <chr> <chr>     <int>
 1 F     Aabha        35
 2 F     Aabriella    32
 3 F     Aada          5
 4 F     Aaden         5
 5 F     Aadhira      77
 6 F     Aadhvika      9
 7 F     Aadhya     1478
 8 F     Aadi         16
 9 F     Aadilynn      5
10 F     Aadison      11
# … with 67,036 more rows
```

And then I finish it by trying to get the top 10 highest values by using head(), but that produces the same results as the line above it.

I have also tried this add_count() function and it spits out the same n value, which is way too high:

```
> add_count(babynames, wt=NULL, sort = FALSE, name = "n")
# A tibble: 1,924,665 x 5
    year sex   name            n   prop
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>       <int>  <dbl>
 1  1880 F     Mary      1924665 0.0724
 2  1880 F     Anna      1924665 0.0267
 3  1880 F     Emma      1924665 0.0205
 4  1880 F     Elizabeth 1924665 0.0199
 5  1880 F     Minnie    1924665 0.0179
 6  1880 F     Margaret  1924665 0.0162
 7  1880 F     Ida       1924665 0.0151
 8  1880 F     Alice     1924665 0.0145
 9  1880 F     Bertha    1924665 0.0135
10  1880 F     Sarah     1924665 0.0132
# … with 1,924,655 more rows
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. *"But I need to find another approach as well."* What are the requirements for the "other" approach?

Comment: Can you be more precise about the desired output?

Comment: @MauritsEvers There are no requirements for the approach. Just not allowed to use the approach I mentioned because that was found online, so I'm trying to work through a different way

Comment: @BillO'Brien the desired output should be the names that come from this code: babynames %>%
  group_by(sex, name) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(n)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total)) %$%
  split(., sex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked about "another approach", how about a base R solution (no external libraries required)?

```
lst <- lapply(
    split(babynames, babynames$sex),
    function(x) {
        df <- aggregate(n ~ name, data = x, FUN = sum)
        df[order(df$n, decreasing = T)[1:5], ]
    })
lst
#$F
#           name       n
#41738      Mary 4123200
#18700 Elizabeth 1629679
#48449  Patricia 1571692
#27718  Jennifer 1466281
#37748     Linda 1452249
#
#$M
#         name       n
#17080   James 5150472
#19152    John 5115466
#32106  Robert 4814815
#26918 Michael 4350824
#39123 William 4102604
```

This returns a `list` of `data.frame`s; if you prefer a single `data.frame`, you can do

```
do.call(rbind, lst)
#             name       n
#F.41738      Mary 4123200
#F.18700 Elizabeth 1629679
#F.48449  Patricia 1571692
#F.27718  Jennifer 1466281
#F.37748     Linda 1452249
#M.17080     James 5150472
#M.19152      John 5115466
#M.32106    Robert 4814815
#M.26918   Michael 4350824
#M.39123   William 4102604
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to find top 5 most common names, split by male/female, over the span of some amount of years as mentioned in the first line of your post. You could do the following : `filter` the data for the specified years, `group_by` `sex` and `name` and calculate the `sum` of `n` and get the top 5 values for each `sex`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(babynames)

start_year <- 1950
end_year <- 2000

babynames %>%
  filter(year >= start_year & year <= end_year) %>%
  group_by(sex, name) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
  top_n(5, n)


#   sex   name           n
#   <chr> <chr>      <int>
# 1 F     Jennifer 1387519
# 2 F     Jessica   949989
# 3 F     Linda     872107
# 4 F     Lisa      952589
# 5 F     Mary     1284713
# 6 M     David    2606708
# 7 M     James    2592627
# 8 M     John     2495291
# 9 M     Michael  3536082
#10 M     Robert   2419214
```

---

We can translate the above in base R

```
df1 <- aggregate(n~sex+name, subset(babynames, year >= start_year & year <= end_year), sum)
df2 <- df1[with(df1, order(sex, -n)), ]
df2[with(df2, ave(n, sex, FUN = seq_along) <= 5), ]
```

Comment: Thanks that helps. However, is there a way that I can find my expected output without using the %>%'s? I am kind of confused on how to use those, so if there is an alternative way without %>% that would be perfect!

Comment: You can always get rid of the %>% (pipes), but it would be a lot tougher to read and reason about the code

Comment: @samrizz4 Added an approach with base R.